# Failed to initialize COM object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, com, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have created a web application in ASP.NET using VB.NET as code behind file. I am using a COM object of ProvideX.Script class to connect to Sage MAS90 ERP. Everything was working fine in visual studio 2010. Now when I moved to the deployment phase, the problem gets started.... I deployed my application in Windows Server 2008 in IIS7. When I run the application I get the following exception... 
This is the line of code where I get the exception...

**Set oPVX = Server.CreateObject("ProvideX.Script")**

I have given the full permissions to IUSR and IIS_USRS accounts, but still getting this error. Also I have registered the ProvideX OLE Server in dcomcnfg.exe ...
I have no ideas what to do..... plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz help me, I have to submit the project in few days...

Server Error in '/' Application.

Failed to initialize the ProvideX library

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Failed to initialize the ProvideX library

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x80020009): Failed to initialize the ProvideX library]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) +792
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) +182
   _Default.btnEnter_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +457
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +120
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5349

Answer (score 0):

You might want to contact the ProvideX people.  See the following thread -- it appears your problem might require some kind of activation:

http://pvx.astecom.nl/show_bericht.php?topic=15804

Answer (score 0):

I detailed out the steps I had to go through on the following site when I had a simmilar issue.  Hopefully it helps.  http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1640098&page=1